# Microsoft BotBuilder Azure OAuth Authentication ConnectionSettingName value

Tags: botframework

I am following [microsoft's dotnet core sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/24.bot-authentication-msgraph), and under the [try this sample section](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/24.bot-authentication-msgraph#to-try-this-sample) it says:

> - Update ConnectionSettingName in GraphAuthenticationBot.cs so the bot can perform OAuth calls through Azure Bot Service

What should the value of `ConnectionSettingName` be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in GraphAuthenticationBot.cs file, you need update below string to the name you have given while creating a connection in Azure Portal.

```
    private const string ConnectionSettingName = "";
```

[image]

[image]